# Error: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower' - with regards to CountVectorizer and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have trouble applying CountVectorizer to an Excel imported dataset. I tried swapping all the integers in the data for a string, but CountVectorizer still registers integers.

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer as cv
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


pos = pd.read_excel("/content/drive/My Drive/Polarity_pos.xlsx", header = None, names=None)

neg = pos = pd.read_excel("/content/drive/My Drive/Polarity_neg.xlsx", header = None, names=None)


merged_train = pd.merge(pos,neg)


string = merged_train.astype('str')

train=pd.DataFrame(data=string).replace('\d+','NUM',regex=True)


print(train.loc[19,:])


#analyzer='word',stop_words=None,analyzer = 'word' 
vectorizer = cv()
count_vector = vectorizer.fit_transform(train)
```

With the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-116-adcd263d8e89> in <module>()
     26 #analyzer='word',stop_words=None,analyzer = 'word'
     27 vectorizer = cv()
---> 28 count_vector = vectorizer.fit_transform(train)
     29 
     30 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _preprocess(doc, accent_function, lower)
     66     """
     67     if lower:
---> 68         doc = doc.lower()
     69     if accent_function is not None:
     70         doc = accent_function(doc)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that you are providing the wrong input to `fit_transform` for the `CountVectorizer`. It doesn't take a dataframe, but an "iterable over raw text documents." See the [docs.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) So you can try to flatten your dataframe and then use the vectorizer. But make sure what you are doing is still fitting your problem. Try this:

```
count_vector = vectorizer.fit_transform(train.stack())
```

Where `train.stack()` transforms your dataframe to a series.